# Targeting a class in a custom base template in FancyBox3

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I have created a custom base template like so:

```js
baseTpl :
'<div class="fancybox-container" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">' +
    '<div class="fancybox-bg"></div>' +
    '<div class="fancybox-inner">' +
        '<div class="fancybox-infobar">' +
            '<span data-fancybox-index></span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<span data-fancybox-count></span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="fancybox-toolbar">{{buttons}}</div>' +
        '<div class="fancybox-navigation">{{arrows}}</div>' +
        '<div class="fancybox-stage"></div>' +
        '<div class="fancybox-social">' +
            '<button class="sharefb" title="Share FaceBook" data-share="hello"></button>' +
            '<button class="sharetwt" title="Share Twitter" data-share="hello"></button>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>',
```

How do I target the custom class sharefb? As I want to dynamically change the data-share attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried doing click() inside document ready but the click event was not firing. Though found out if I move it inside the fancybox options then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You event needs to be delegated, you will bubble the click event using a parent element, in my case the body:

```
$('body').on('click','.sharefb',function(){
   $(this).attr('data-share','new value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can just do like this inside a fancybox instance inside opts:

```
afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
    $('.fancybox-social .sharefb').click(function(){
        //add your js here                        
    });
```